# Restriction of Inverse Image of Tautological Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let consider the scheme $S:= \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and denote the canonical projection morphism by $pr_i: S \to \mathbb{P}^1$ for $i = 1,2$.

Define invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}:= pr_1 ^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1))$ on $S$.

Let $a \in \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $pr_i^{-1}(a) \cong \mathbb{P}^1$.

My question is why does for the restriction of $ \mathcal{L}$ to $pr_2^{-1}(a) $ holds

$$\mathcal{L} \vert_{pr_2^{-1}(a)} =  \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any $a \in \Bbb P^1$ verify $pr_i^{-1}(a) \cong \Bbb P^1$ (if at least you consider only closed points). Anyway, if we rephrase everything in terms of divisors, notice that $$(\{a'\} \times \Bbb P^1) \cap (\Bbb P^1 \times \{a\}) = \{a'\} \times \{a\}$$

which means exactly that $L_{|pr_2^{-1}(a)} \cong \mathcal O_{\Bbb P^1}(1)$.

This is because if $D \subset X$ is a divisor and $Y \subset X$ is a variety, then $D$ corresponds to a line bundle $L$ and $Y \cdot D$ (intersection product) is a divisor on $Y$, corresponding to $L_{|Y}$.

Also I should say that usually what is called the tautological sheaf is $\mathcal O_{\Bbb P^1}(-1)$.

Comment: If I understood your argument with intersection product correctly, then it suffices to show that a closed point $\{d\} $ interpreted as divisor corresponds to the line bundle /invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$, right? 
Therefore it suffices to show that for the sequence  
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \to \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{O}_{\{d\}} \to 0 $$ 
where $\mathcal{O}_{\{d\}}$ is the stucture sheaf of the closed point, we have $\mathcal{D}= \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$, right? 
Here I don't see how to verify this.

Comment: That's true. This is a very standard sequence : check that $O(-1)$ is the ideal sheaf of a point. So we have the sequence $0 \to O(-1) \to O \to O_p \to 0$ and tensoring by $O(1)$ yields the result (for a skyscraper sheaf $F$ and a line bundle $L$ we have $F \otimes L \cong F$).

Comment: Naively I would argue as follows: The global sections of $O(-1) $ are linear polynomials $l$, so if $\{p\}$ corresponds to the maximal ideal $m=(x-a,y-b)$ where $(a,b)$ is the unique zero of $l$, then obviously $l$ (as multiplication map) would give a rise for the sequence $0 \to O(-1) \to O \to O_p \to 0$. But this only works only if the closed points (resp. max ideals) are all of the shape $(x-a,y-b)$, right? But if we consider $S$ not to be over a alg closed field (like complex numbers) then it might have locally max ideals (so close points) of other shape than $(x-a,y-b)$.

Comment: What can be done in this case to get the wished sequence?

Comment: I don't think the sequence works if $k$ is not algebraically closed. But I'm not very familiar with non-algebraically closed fields.

Comment: But did you have the same idea in mind to get the sequence $0 \to O(-1) \to O \to O_p \to 0$ as I tried to explain above using global sections? Or is there another "canonical" method to derive such one?

Comment: Hi, again. I thought meanwhile a bit about this method using intersection product but one point stays unclear: It says that if $D, D'$ are divisors and the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{G} = \mathcal{O}_X(D')$ corresponds to divisor $D'$ then it says $(D'*D)= deg(\mathcal{G} \vert _D) = h^0(\mathcal{O}_{D \cap D'})$. In our situation $D=\{a'\} \times \Bbb P^1, D'=\Bbb P^1 \times \{a\}$, so $D' \cap D =  \{a'\} \times \{a\} \cong p$. But to apply this don't we should know that $\mathcal{L}:= pr_1 ^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1))$ has corresponing divisor $D'$? How to see that this holds?

Comment: The main problem to me seems to be in what happens with $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1))$ after applying here $pr_1 ^*$...

Comment: @KarlPeter : If $f$ is flat then $f^*O_Y(D) = O_X(f^*D)$.

Comment: I suppose here $f^*D$ is the topological pull back, and since fibers are stable (isomorphic) under pull backs in this context we have $pr_1^*(\{a'\} \times \Bbb P^1) \cong pr_1^{-1}(p)$. Do you have a reference of a proof of $f^*O_Y(D) = O_X(f^*D)$?